# How to update the option by json result in Dart

Tags: dart

My option values are download from server. How can I update the option values after server return result?

```
 <select name="book" template iterate="book in books" bind-value="selected">
 <option selected="{{selected == book}}">{{book}}</option>
 </select>
```

In .dart

```
 List<String> books= <String>[''];
 @observable
 String selected = 'Doraemon';
 void main() {
      var request = HttpRequest.getString(url).then((jstr){
      // Parse json
      Map data = json.parse(jstr);
      print(data['option']['books']);
      // Refresh the list, but how to refresh option value?
      books.addAll(data['option']['books']);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap the books value in a call to "toObservable". https://www.dartlang.org/web-ui/observables/#observing-collections

```
List<String> books= toObservable(<String>['']);
```